# Github action, npm install give 'code EINTEGRITY' 'integrity checksum failed'

Tags: npm, github-actions, npm-install

I made a simple github action, but `npm ci` gives the error below:

```
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-50ruizEwP94JN7XxBDqTSwC0kQRdcyxKFV8YLFEGqyXmYv8WTumz/b2qk7MDCZRlQjljN+FvmjN65kVyIVTO4g== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-50ruizEwP94JN7XxBDqTSwC0kQRdcyxKFV8YLFEGqyXmYv8WTumz/b2qk7MDCZRlQjljN+FvmjN65kVyIVTO4g== but got sha512-L3u8IGvSbriTzpIxcit5NH3q8P9uA331KVvk9+hj1mbepL77y7wMLatDSB45QaN+9iJQ3ZWi14Ph0FvAysXBGA==. (3291 bytes)
```

I found other SO posts about this, but those are for old npm versions or where cache needs to be cleared. This is inside a github action.

The full source and output can be found [here](https://github.com/roelandmoors/authjs-adapter-mysql2/actions/runs/4582275881/jobs/8092394597):

```
Run npm ci
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @next-auth/adapter-test@https://gitpkg.now.sh/nextauthjs/next-auth/packages/adapter-test?main (sha512-50ruizEwP94JN7XxBDqTSwC0kQRdcyxKFV8YLFEGqyXmYv8WTumz/b2qk7MDCZRlQjljN+FvmjN65kVyIVTO4g==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @next-auth/tsconfig@https://gitpkg.now.sh/nextauthjs/next-auth/packages/tsconfig?main (sha512-IJoQ8gcPDDd4+0hMyke4nIgGYUjxeU78nF6+Gm+ZmIRvRojj3CKznAN5Hvrws2xYUgeN0kdxzINS/aanq75wxg==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @next-auth/adapter-test@https://gitpkg.now.sh/nextauthjs/next-auth/packages/adapter-test?main (sha512-50ruizEwP94JN7XxBDqTSwC0kQRdcyxKFV8YLFEGqyXmYv8WTumz/b2qk7MDCZRlQjljN+FvmjN65kVyIVTO4g==) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha512-50ruizEwP94JN7XxBDqTSwC0kQRdcyxKFV8YLFEGqyXmYv8WTumz/b2qk7MDCZRlQjljN+FvmjN65kVyIVTO4g== integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted sha512-50ruizEwP94JN7XxBDqTSwC0kQRdcyxKFV8YLFEGqyXmYv8WTumz/b2qk7MDCZRlQjljN+FvmjN65kVyIVTO4g== but got sha512-L3u8IGvSbriTzpIxcit5NH3q8P9uA331KVvk9+hj1mbepL77y7wMLatDSB45QaN+9iJQ3ZWi14Ph0FvAysXBGA==. (3291 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-04-01T08_41_36_158Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I use [gitpkg](https://gitpkg.vercel.app/) to link a GIT subfolder. Could that cause the problem? Is that not supported inside a github action?

```
"@next-auth/adapter-test": "https://gitpkg.now.sh/nextauthjs/next-auth/packages/adapter-test?main",
"@next-auth/tsconfig": "https://gitpkg.now.sh/nextauthjs/next-auth/packages/tsconfig?main",
```

**update:**
I noticed this warning: `tarball data for ... seems to be corrupted`. I guess download from gitpkg doesn't work.

Comment: Please post the relevant lines from the log here as well. Only people with an account on github can read it otherwise and search engines won't be able to index the relevant messages with the question which makes it harder for others to find this question.

Comment: Wasn't the private key from the npmjs.org registry compromised? It's probably got something to do with that

Comment: Ah no it was the "git ssh rsa key" from github.com that was replaced last week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran npm ci locally on a dev-vm and that fails with the same errors:

[image: Same EINTEGRITY errors when running npm ci locally]

The package is added using the git branch, in this case it is simply `main`. So when the author of the package updates the code in `main`, its hashes change. But the package reference stays exactly the same. So now there are 2 different hashes for the same package. So the downloading of the tarball succeeds, but GitHub actions is receiving a newer tarball than the one you have in your npm cache.

Your local npm cache on your developer machine will have the package cached, so it won't need to update the package and thus the old hash remains in the `package-lock.json`.

GitHub Actions doesn't have a cached version, so it downloads a fresh copy (with the exact same name and version since you're pulling from `main`). But gets new contents and thus a different hash.

This setup doesn't lend itself well to using `npm ci`. You should either

- replace the `?main` with a fixed tag on that repo, e.g. `?4.20.1`
- or clear your local npm cache every time the repos are updated, run `npm install`, commit the `package-lock.json` and then push that
- or rely on `npm install` in your actions workflow instead of <s>`npm ci`</s>, since that will ignore the package integrity.

Comment: Perfect answer. I linked to a tag and it works now. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, once you figure out what is all cached and calculated in the background it makes total sense. But until then just a frustrating set of messages.

Comment: Is it possible that your third option is incorrect? It seems `install` also checks integrity

Comment: @roeland I might be mistaking here, but from what I understand it will check the integrity of the newly downloaded file against what the registry reports. Not against the lock file. But if you happen to know any docs that explain this in good detail, let me know.